# MySQL changes 'changed' column on update by itself

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table test (id int, changed timestamp);

insert into test (id, changed) values (1, now());
insert into test (id, changed) values (2, now());
insert into test (id, changed) values (3, now());

select * from test;

+----+---------------------+
| id | changed             |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | 2015-07-14 14:58:00 | <-- correct
| 2  | 2015-07-14 14:58:02 |
| 3  | 2015-07-14 14:58:04 |
+----+---------------------+


update test set id = 5 where id = 1;  -- nothing with 'changed' specified!

select * from test;

+----+---------------------+
| id | changed             |
+----+---------------------+
| 5  | 2015-07-14 15:00:00 | <-- wrong! why?
| 2  | 2015-07-14 14:58:02 |
| 3  | 2015-07-14 14:58:04 |
+----+---------------------+
```

See the column changed, i wanted to set id and not changed. First time that a database does this on me.

**Why does MySQL do that?**

**How can I stop that behaviour?**

Comment: Seems like the time part is changed to the time the record was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you used the `timestamp` data type for the 'changed' column, which updates every time the row is updated.

If you wanted this to work as expected I would change the 'changed' data type to `datetime` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 1):

By default a `TIMESTAMP` column will be set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and this will also be used whenever you updating the row.

When you create you table using:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id int,
  changed TIMESTAMP
);
```

It will be the same as this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id int,
  changed TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

With a constant, the default is the given value. In this case, the column has no automatic properties at all:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id int,
  changed TIMESTAMP 0
);
```

Comment: Thank you, the datetime method is cleaner for my case.

Answer (score 0):

A `timestamp` column is automatically updated:

> With neither DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP nor ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it is the same as specifying both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

See the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html).